# Return specific row and column values of all instances of a value in a table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table.

|  | ID | Follow-up 1 | Follow-up 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12082023-01 | 15-08-2023 | 19-08-2023 |
| 2 | 12082023-02 | 15-08-2023 | 19-08-2023 |
| 3 | 12082023-03 | 15-08-2023 | 19-08-2023 |
| 4 | 13082023-01 | 16-08-2023 | 20-08-2023 |
| 5 | 13082023-02 | 16-08-2023 | 20-08-2023 |
| 6 | 13082023-03 | 16-08-2023 | 20-08-2023 |
| 7 | 13082023-04 | 16-08-2023 | 20-08-2023 |
| 8 | 14082023-01 | 17-08-2023 | 21-08-2023 |
| 9 | 14082023-02 | 17-08-2023 | 21-08-2023 |
| 10 | 14082023-03 | 17-08-2023 | 21-08-2023 |
| 11 | 15082023-01 | 18-08-2023 | 22-08-2023 |
| 12 | 15082023-02 | 18-08-2023 | 22-08-2023 |
| 13 | 16082023-01 | 19-08-2023 | 23-08-2023 |
| 14 | 16082023-02 | 19-08-2023 | 23-08-2023 |
| 15 | 16082023-03 | 19-08-2023 | 23-08-2023 |
| 16 | 16082023-04 | 19-08-2023 | 23-08-2023 |
| 17 | 17082023-05 | 20-08-2023 | 24-08-2023 |
| 18 | 17082023-01 | 20-08-2023 | 24-08-2023 |

Desired output when I put in a date query eg 20-08-2023:

|  | Follow-up Number | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Follow-up 1 | 17082023-05 |
| 2 | Follow-up 1 | 17082023-01 |
| 3 | Follow-up 2 | 13082023-01 |
| 4 | Follow-up 2 | 13082023-02 |
| 5 | Follow-up 2 | 13082023-03 |
| 6 | Follow-up 2 | 13082023-04 |

I tried this with ChatGPT but didn't seem to work. The response is below but I am getting a blank value in Cell I2.

Assuming your table is in the range A1:C19 and you want to categorize follow-ups for the date in cell H1 (e.g., "20-08-2023"), follow these steps:

```
Create a Results Table: Set up a new area where you want the results to be displayed. You can use headers like "Follow-up Number" and "ID." Let's assume you start this results table in cell I1.

Enter Formulas:

    Follow-up Number Column: In cell I2 (Follow-up Number column), use the following formula and drag it down:
```

---

```
=IF(OR($B2=$H$1, $C2=$H$1), "Follow-up " & COUNTIFS($B$2:$C$19, TEXT($H$1, "dd-mm-yyyy"), $A$2:$A$19, $A2), "")
```

ID Column: In cell J2 ( ID column), use the following formula and drag it down:

```
=IF(I2\<\>"", $A2, "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags in the post, then you could try using the following formula :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(IF(F2=B2:C19,A2:A19,NA()),3),
     b,TOCOL(IF(F2=B2:C19,B1:C1,NA()),3),
     VSTACK({"Follow-up Number","ID"},SORT(HSTACK(b,a),1)))
```

---

Or, instead of <kbd>IF( )</kbd> we can use <kbd>IFS( )</kbd> aslo,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(IFS(F2=B2:C19,A2:A19),3),
     b,TOCOL(IFS(F2=B2:C19,B1:C1),3),
     VSTACK({"Follow-up Number","ID"},SORT(HSTACK(b,a),1)))
```

---

Solution worked for OP as stated in comments:

• **`Follow-up Number`**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$1,,AGGREGATE(15,7,
(COLUMN($B$1:$C$1)-COLUMN($B$1)+1)/($F$2=$B$2:$C$19),ROW(A1))),"")
```

---

• **`ID`**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$19,AGGREGATE(14,7,
(ROW($A$2:$A$19)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($F$2=$B$2:$C$19),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Comment: Apologies if I missed any details. Apparently the TOCOL function is not available for me. .